# Using Reconcile in ArcGIS Versioning

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, versioning, reconcile

When doing a reconcile in ArcGIS ArcMap (v10.2), you get the Reconcile window as shown in the screenshot.  At the bottom it asks how you want to resolve conflicts (in favor of target or edit version).  Once you hit OK on this window, if there are conflicts, you get a conflict resolution window that shows the conflicts and allows you to choose how each conflict can be resolved, so I'm wondering about the purpose of the conflict question in the reconcile window because if there are conflicts, I get the conflict window anyway.  In other words, it seems to be redundant.  I'm sure I'm missing something in the logic here.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conflict window is a dialog displaying the detected conflicts. It just gives you an opportunity to override the system resolved conflicts manually.
You can hit post or save after reconcile to commit the reconcile results without having to manually resolve them. The system will resolve them based on your settings. If you manually resolved a conflict, then your edits will be committed

Comment: Thank you for the response.  To clarify, if I close the conflict window without manually changing anything, the system will automatically resolve the conflicts based on the setting I chose, correct?

Comment: Yes. You do not have to manually resolve all conflicts in the dialog. Per the docs " If there are conflicts, ArcGIS resolves them in favor of either the edit version or the target version representation, depending on your preference. Once conflicts are resolved, you can review them one at a time and, if necessary, make any changes" http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Reviewing_conflicts. a good discussion on versioning, review http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0110/versioning101.html